# Principles of Physics book question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

> A small block of mass m is sent sliding with velocity v along a slab of mass 10m, starting at a distance of l from the far end of the slab. The coefficient of kinetic friction between the slab and the floor is μ1; that between the block and the slab is μ2, with μ2>11μ1.
>
> (a) Find the minimum value of v such that the block reaches the far end of the slab.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. We don't answer homework type questions on this website.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.